# ROR console output to text file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble saving content from ROR console to my local folder
I already try this approach:

```
path = "C:/folder/folder/path.txt"
content = "data from the form"
File.open(path, "w+") do |f|
  f.write(content)
end
```

Error received upon trying the codes above:
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen
As I understand the error it seems the path ROR looking for should exist on ROR server side.

Goal:
To save 'content' to my local folder (C:\path\path\folder)

Comment: Is the question that you want to save the output to a file on your local machine? Not on the actual server's directory?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's difficult to tell what you mean. Code running on the server is going to use the OS's paths for the server, and a "local" file will be on the server. By "local" do you mean the server, or your client machine? Please edit your question and fill in the blanks as if you'd added that information when you first asked it.

Comment: Hi both, already edited the question with clearer vision of what I my problem is. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the private key in accessing the ROR server and insert it into filezilla.
By then login thru filezilla, hostname should be ROR host and user type should be interactive.

Answer (score 0):

You could only "download" a file if it exists on the server. Following method will write your content to log.txt which will be initially placed on your server rails root, then it'll prompt you to download the file.

```
def logger_meth
  content = "data from the form"
  File.open("#{Rails.root}/log.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write(content) }
  log_file = "#{Rails.root}/log.txt"
  send_file log_file, :type=>"application/text", :x_sendfile=>true
end
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response,
I don't know if I run your script correctly but when I'm testing this
I received

NoMethodError: undefined method `send_file' for main:Object

Comment: This will only work from an ActionController - you can't use it purely in the console.